# Socket.io makes connection on https://domain but doesnt make any on https://domain/route

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Okay as I said i the title when I go to my home page the socket connection works perfectly but when I use a route it doesnt work at all here is my index.js

```
io.of('/admin').on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
  console.log(socket.request.user);
  socket.on('chat', async function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    client.guilds.channels.get('474951005788962846').send(data);
    io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
  });
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  console.log('made socket connection', socket.id);
  console.log(socket.request.user);
  socket.on('chat', async function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    client.guilds.channels.get('474951005788962846').send(data);
    io.sockets.emit('chat', data);
  });
});
```

and on my /admin page here is my script that it is the same but the connection isnt as I added the /admin

```
<script>
    var socket = io.connect('https://domain/admin');


// Query DOM
var serverID = document.getElementById('add_server_id');
var serverRoles = document.getElementById('add_role_ids');
var btnServer = document.getElementById('add_server_save');
//var output = document.getElementById('output');

// Emit events

btnServer.addEventListener('click', function(){
    socket.emit('chat', {
        serverid: serverID.value,
        serverroles: serverRoles.value
    });
});

//Listen for events
socket.on('chat', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  //output.innerHTML += '<p><strong>' + data.game + '</strong></p>';
});
  </script>
```

if someone can tell me why is it not connecting I would really appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var socket = io.connect('https://domain/admin');
```

to

```
var socket = io.connect('/admin');
```

> The namespace is an implementation detail of the Socket.IO protocol,
>   and is not related to the actual URL of the underlying transport,
>   which defaults to /socket.io/….

Comment: Okay i changed it but it is still not making the connection